# OpenDKIM on Fedora Server, opendkim-testkey loads the key, says it's checking it, then just says "query failed" How do I find (and fix) what's wrong?

Tags: opendkim, fedora-server, fedora-37

On `Fedora Server` 37 (updated as of about February 1, 2023), a new `OpenDKIM` installation was performed (it's version v2.11.0). The configuration included creating a signing table and a key table, and creation of a key, as well as publishing it in `DNS`. So far, so good...

I got to the point where you test it via `opendkim-testkey` and this failed.

The first time I ran it it complained "unsafe permissions", though that didn't stop it, however, I focused on that for a bit; NOTHING I did - changing ownerships and permissions in a half dozen or more permutations - made that error go away, so to heck with it for now!

I recognized that there must have been an error in the signing table, so I made a subtle change. ...It apparently demands to use "_domainkey", even though the official documentation doesn't say that's required and it seems purely unnecessary for it to do so, but apparently that's required. And I think so because when I comported with the seemingly silly addition of this "_domainkey" text to the entry in the signing table, it got further along, at least now saying it's loading the correct `keyfile`. Yet, I still get the "query failed" error.

To be clear, the session goes like this:

```
opendkim-testkey -d some-fqdn.com -s default -vvvvvvv
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: /etc/opendkim/keys/some-fqdn.com/<prefix>.private: WARNING: unsafe permissions
opendkim-testkey: key loaded from /etc/opendkim/keys/some-fqdn.com/<prefix>.private
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.some-fqdn.com'
opendkim-testkey: 'default._domainkey.some-fqdn.com' query failed
```

Well, thanks for the clue, `opendkim-testkey`!

I got nothing helpful from `systemctl status opendkim.service` - it says it's status is "active (running)" with no errors. So, I checked the log (in this case `/var/log/messages`), and there were some entries. So, to be sure they're current, I cycled `opendkim` with `systemctl reload` while `grep`ping on a `tail -f` command and got:

```
Mar  5 11:17:21 fs1 systemd[1]: Started opendkim.service - DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Mar  5 11:17:21 fs1 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='unit=opendkim comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Mar  5 11:17:22 fs1 abrt-notification[3173323]: Process 348313 (opendkim) crashed in _nl_load_domain.cold()
```

WHOAH! Crashed? Why does it say it's up and running then?! Strange!

Some investigation shows that _nl_load_domain.cold() is in fact a C++ function.

The function definition begins:

```
internal_function
_nl_find_domain (const char *dirname, char *locale,
         const char *domainname, struct binding *domainbinding)
{
  struct loaded_l10nfile *retval;
  const char *language;
  const char *modifier;
  const char *territory;
  const char *codeset;
  const char *normalized_codeset;
  const char *alias_value;
  int mask;
```

That's enough to make this guy go: "Hmmm... what now?!"

(Note that the domain in question is working just fine - except for `opendkim`! - with a fairly robust `DNS zone` that's live, AND, the system in question has full access to `DNS` queries.)

**NOTE**
`OpenDKIM` is validating inbound email `DKIM` keys just fine! I just need to get the signing part working, too!